# Div shows when mouse in and hide when move out

Tags: jquery, css

All, 
Forgive me I don't know how to put the question in words. so I think better to tall about my code and what I want to do with it . thanks.

Say you have this code .

```
<div class="father">
<div id ="container1" class="container">
    <div class="head">

    </div>
    <div class="content">
    </div>
</div>
<div id ="container2" class="container">
    <div class="head">

    </div>
    <div class="content">
    </div>
</div>
</div>

.father
{
    min-height:300px;
    border:1px solid black;

}
#container1
{
    float:left;
    border:1px solid red;
    width:48%;
    min-height:200px;
}
#container2
{
    float:left;
    border:1px solid blue;
    width:48%;
    min-height:200px;
}
.head
{
     height:20px;
     border:1px solid purple;

}
.content
{
    height:40px;
    border:1px solid green;


}
$(function(){
    $(".head").css("display","none");
    $(".container").hover(function(){$(".head",this).css("display","block");},function(){$(".head",this).css("display","none");});

})
```

http://jsfiddle.net/malaikuangren/LuPhd/

What I trying to do is when mouse move in the $(".container), I want to show the $(".head") in the current $(".container), But so far . this div show and hide make the layout break(you can see the $(".content") is moving when the .head show and hide . ).It means I want to the $(".head") show over and in the $(".container) when mouse in. please help me ,thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

live fiddle [**here**](http://jsfiddle.net/62HEH/8/)

**HTML**

```
<div class="father">
<div id ="container1" class="container">
     <div class="head">
    </div>
    <div class="content">
    </div>
</div>
<div id ="container2" class="container">
    <div class="head">

    </div>
    <div class="content">
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.father
{
    min-height:300px;
    border:1px solid black;

}
.container
{
    width:48%;
    min-height:200px;
}
#container1
{
    float:left;
    border:1px solid red;
}
#container2
{
    float:left;
    border:1px solid blue;
}
.head
{
    height:20px;
    border:1px dotted purple;
    z-index:9999;
    position:absolute;
    display:none;
}
.content
{
    height:40px;
    border:1px solid green;
}
```

**jQuery**

```
$(function(){
    $(".head").width($('.container').width());
    $(".container").hover(function(){$(".head", this).show()},function(){$(".head",this).hide();});  
});
```

you should use **`show()`** rather than `.css("display","block")` and **`hide()`** instead of `.css("display","none")`, more information [**here**](http://api.jquery.com/show/) and [**here**](http://api.jquery.com/hide/).

Comment: Hi , Friend, In your example the head's width exceed the width of parent. thanks.

Comment: @Joe.wang Updated answer and fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

You can change your `.head` class like this

```
.head
{
     height:20px;
     border:1px solid purple;
     position: absolute;    

}
```

and your javascript code like this

```
$(function(){
     $(".head").css("display","none");
    $(".container").hover(function(){$(".head",this).css("display","block");
         $(".head",this).width($(this).width());},
                          function(){$(".head",this).css("display","none");}
                         );});
```

Comment: Hi, @Hasan Ayan But In my case ,I am not sure the width it is . In the example I just demo the question. What can I do with this case ?thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You have to change your CSS and jQuery Code a little bit...

jQuery:

```
// get the width of the container
    var box_width = $(this).css("width");
    $(".head",this).css("width",""+box_width+"");
```

CSS:

```
.head{
 height:20px;
 border:1px solid purple;
position:absolute;}
```

Hope this will help ;)

Comment: Hi , Friend ,This way is not recommended way to do that . I ever try in this way . but sometimes it is not precise .

Comment: Hi, why shouldn't it be precise? Because of the css() function?

Answer (score 0):

You could use opacity as well to show/hide the .head style

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/LuPhd/13/

When you use `display:none;` and `display:block;` it removes and adds the whole .head div which is why the layout breaks.

JQuery:

```
$(function(){
    $(".container").hover(function()    
      {$(".head",this).css("opacity","1");},function()
      {$(".head",this).css("opacity","0");});                      
})
```

CSS:

```
.head
{
     opacity:0;
     height:20px;
     border:1px solid purple;

}
```

Alternatively you could use `.show` and `.hide` instead of Opacity.